# Repeated series of number via CSS

Tags: css, css-counter

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<h2>1.1 Bananas</h2>
<h3>1.1.1 </h3>
<h3>1.1.2 </h3>
<h3>1.1.3 </h3>

<h2>1.1 Apples</h2>
<h3>1.1.1 </h3>
<h3>1.1.2 </h3>
<h3>1.1.3 </h3>

<h2>1.1 Oranges</h2>
<h3>1.1.1</h3>
<h3>1.1.2</h3>
<h3>1.1.3</h3>
```

Notice how the number series repeats.

I can do autonumbering via CSS - but I can't figure out if there's a way to repeat the numbered series.

Comment: i never knew you could do autonumbering with css. how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way would to be use CSS [`counters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters) and reset them every time a `h2` is encountered like in below snippet.

The `counter-reset` property within the `h2` selector sets the value of the `h2` counter to 1 and that of the `h3` counter to 0 (default) everytime a `h2` element is encountered.

The `counter-increment` property within the `h3` selector increments the value of the `h3` counter everytime a `h3` element is encountered.

```css
h2 {
  counter-reset: h2 1 h3 0;
}
h2:before {
  content: "1." counter(h2);
}
h3 {
  counter-increment: h3;
}
h3:before {
  content: "1." counter(h2)"." counter(h3);
}
```

```html
<h2>Bananas</h2> <!-- h2 counter = 1, h3 counter = 0 -->
<h3></h3> <!-- h2 counter = 1, h3 counter = 1 (increment) -->
<h3></h3> <!-- h2 counter = 1, h3 counter = 2 (increment) -->
<h3></h3> <!-- h2 counter = 1, h3 counter = 3 (increment) -->
<h2>Apples</h2> <!-- h2 counter = 1 (reset), h3 counter = 0 (reset) -->
<h3></h3> <!-- h2 counter = 1, h3 counter = 1 (increment) -->
<h3></h3> <!-- h2 counter = 1, h3 counter = 2 (increment) -->
<h3></h3> <!-- h2 counter = 1, h3 counter = 3 (increment) -->
<h2>Oranges</h2> <!-- h2 counter = 1 (reset), h3 counter = 0 (reset) -->
<h3></h3> <!-- h2 counter = 1, h3 counter = 1 (increment) -->
<h3></h3> <!-- h2 counter = 1, h3 counter = 2 (increment) -->
<h3></h3> <!-- h2 counter = 1, h3 counter = 3 (increment) -->
```

---

Actually, you don't even need the `h2` counter for your case because the value is always 1. So even the below in CSS would suffice:

```
h2 {
  counter-reset: h3 0;
}
h2:before {
  content: "1.1";
}
h3 {
  counter-increment: h3;
}
h3:before {
  content: "1.1." counter(h3);
}
```

Comment: Technically, the number wouldn't always begin with a one. I just happened to start it with a 1 in this example.

Comment: Oh ok @FlareforHelp. In that case you would just have to use another counter for the top most level and increment or reset as required. Don't forget to mark as accepted if you are satisfied with the answer :)