# Style an Ordered List like "X.X" based on list start attribute

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I would like to style an ordered list like this for a client, but am not sure exactly how. The client wishes to have a policy page, with several sections. Each section has several statements, which are numbered like so: "x.1, x.2" (where "x" is dependent on the section number). Here is what the HTML looks like for the sections:

```
<div class="customListBox">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <ol>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ol>

    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <ol>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

This is what is should wind up showing:

---

### Section 1

1.1 Item 1
1.2 Item 2
1.3 Item 3

### Section 2

2.1 Item 1
2.2 Item 2

---

I have looked at several other questions, but almost all of them involve nested lists, **which I wish to stay away from**, as this induces problems with other site styles. I am aware of the CSS counters, but am unsure if I can use them without nesting lists. Also, the page is a dynamic JSP page, so if there is a way to do this in JSP, that would be sufficient.

Related question of mine that gives entire scope of project...I think it is too unclear, so I started this one with barebones code. I felt that even if I edited the other one, the other answers and comments on the page (caused by my first and very unclear question) could cause confusion to future visitors.
[Style an Ordered List like "1.1, 1.2, 1.3"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859932/style-an-ordered-list-like-1-1-1-2-instead-of-1-2)

This question is similar, but involves nested lists, which I need to avoid due to existing styles. Also, I do not want "x" numbers, or "x.x.x" numbers; I only want "x.x" numbers.
[Can ordered list produce result like "1, 1.2, 1.3"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1)

Let me know if I should clarify anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CSS Counters](http://caniuse.com/#search=counters) and the [counter-increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters) declaration.

Edit: Updated snippet to use class name and adjusted the pseudo-element positioning.

Edit 2: Updated snippet to only target first level list items.

```css
 /* Whatever your defaults are */
ol {
  list-style-type:upper-alpha;
  position:relative;
}

/* Targets only .customListBox's first level child ol elements */
.customListBox > ol { 
    counter-increment: lists;
    counter-reset: items;
    list-style-type: none;
}

 /* Targets only the first level child li elements of the first ol's in .customListBox*/
.customListBox > ol > li::before {
    content: counters(lists, "", decimal) "." counters(items, "", decimal) " ";
    counter-increment: items;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="customListBox">
  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  <ol>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item
      <ol>
        <li>Sub Item</li>
        <li>Sub Item</li>
        <li>Sub Item</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ol>

  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  <ol>
    <li>Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Long Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Except that when the item wraps, it doesn't align with the first line, but rather aligns at the left of the number. Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: Just position the pseudo-element absolutely...that should do it.

Comment: @Kendall Roth - Paulie_D is correct and I have updated the snippet with the absolute positioning and it should fix your problem.

Comment: @IMI Thanks. It's much closer. I should note that I have now taken out class="specialList" and instead chosen to follow your previous edit, and put a <div class="customListContainer"> around all of the lists.

Comment: @KendallRoth - Do you consider this the answer to your question or does it need more refinement?

Comment: @IMI I think it's extremely close, but I am still trying to implement perfectly it with corporate styling. PS. Have edited question somewhat

Comment: @KendallRoth - After re-reading the question, It appears that you only want to target the first list elements with the X.X numbering and not sub-lists. So, I have updated the snippet to target only those first lists.

Comment: Thanks for your help IMI! I was finally able to get this working using the absolute positioning and your targeting update. I had to slightly reshape the page, but I don't think my contact will mind!